# Output entries that have the highest score

Tags: text-processing

I have a file as below. Based on the score column, I would like to output just the people with the highest scores for each subject by printing the entire line as below. A particular order is not needed, but the subject column should have all unique entries.

```
name subject score remarks
john   Math    67   satis
lewis  History 56   poor
sarah  Math    89   good
fiona  Geo     65   satis
george History 99   very good
```

Output desired:

```
name   subject score remarks
sarah  Math    89   good
george History 99   very good
fiona  Geo     65   satis
```

All columns are tab-separated and only the remarks column have space separated words. If the same score exists for same subject I would like to output all of those people.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```hs
{
head -n 1 file.txt &&
tail -n+2 file.txt |
sort -t $'\t' -nrk 3 |
awk -F '\t' 's[$2] && s[$2] > $3 { next }{ s[$2] = $3 } 1'
} >outfile.txt
```

- `head -n1` to print header.
- `tail -n+2` to skip header and pipe rest for processing.
- `sort` Do a numeric reverse sort (high to low) (`-rn`). Sort by column 3 (`-k 3`) of input separated by tabs (`-t $'\t'` - could be dropped if there is no spaces in name or subject column).
- `awk` Print line as long as subject is not seen, or it is equal to last.
  `-F '\t'` Set field separator to tab. Could be removed if the name and subject column does not contain spaces.

  - `s[$2] && s[$2] > $3 { next }` Next; if `s[subject]` is set and greater than current value (highest score).
  - `{s[$2] = 1}` set `s[subject] = score`
  - `1` print

---

If you do not mind header at last row and you do not need to consider *names* or *subjects* with spaces (as in: there are none) – it could be shortened to:

```swift
sort -nrk3 file.txt | awk ' s[$2] && s[$2] > $3{next}{s[$2]=$3}1'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
    NR==1              { print; next }
    max[$2]<$3 || NR==2{ max[$2]=$3; data[$2]=$0; next }
    max[$2]==$3        { data[$2]= data[$2] ORS $0 }

END{ for(x in data) print data[x] }' infile
```

---

- `BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }`, set Tab `\t` character as the **F**ield **S**eparator for the input and **O**utput **F**ield **S**eparator for the output.
- `NR==1{ print; next }`, output header-line.
- `max[$2]<$3 || NR==2{ max[$2]=$3; data[$2]=$0; next }`, update and hold the highest score for each subject and also hold the entire line for that high score subject.
- `max[$2]==$3{ data[$2]= data[$2] ORS $0 }`, append those records with the same highest score for each same subject.
- `END{ for(x in data) print data[x] }`, loop over the data array and print the final result.

Answer (score 2):

Use GNU `sort` to sort and `uniq` to take only the first for each subject:

```
sort -t '\t' -r -k 2 -k 3n scores.txt | uniq -f 1 -w 7
```

`-k 2` does sort by the subject (2nd field) and `-k 3n` `n`umerically sorts by the score (3rd field). The `-r` option reverses the sorting order, so the highest score will be first.

Now `uniq` removes double subjects, skipping the first field with `-f 1` and comparing only 5, so this will fail for subjects which share the first 5 chars like `HistoryA` and `HistoryB`.

As for the `uniq` command with `-f` option is used, so the first field must not contain spaces else it will produce wrong output since with that a field is a run of blanks (usually spaces and/or TABs), then non-blank characters. some specific versions and only in Debian `uniq` had `-t` option to specify the field separator but now removed for the compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 2):

GNU `datamash` is also an option, e.g. assuming tab separated values (use `-W` otherwise on the first `datamash` invocation):

```sh
{
  # Print header
  head -n1 scores.txt

  # Group columns by subject,score,remarks
  <scores.txt datamash --header-in -s groupby 2,3,4 collapse 1 |

  # Output maximum score
  datamash -f groupby 1 max 2 |

  # Re-shuffle columns to desired format
  datamash cut 4,1,2,3
} |

# Pretty-print columns
column -s $'\t' -t
```

Test-file with multiple max-score students:

```
name    subject score   remarks
john    Math    67  satis
lewis   History 56  poor
sarah   Math    89  good
fiona   Geo     65  satis
fiona   Math    65  satis
george  History 99  very good
carl    History 99  very good
```

Output:

```
name         subject  score  remarks
fiona        Geo      65     satis
george,carl  History  99     very good
sarah        Math     89     good
```

Comment: The above command now produces the output `datamash: invalid operation ‘cut’`. Though this worked well before.

Comment: @PrabhjotSingh: which version of `datamash` are you using? It works here with version 1.7

Comment: `datamash (GNU datamash) 1.2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==FNR {if ($3>max[$2]) max[$2]=$3; next} FNR==1||$3==max[$2]' file file
```

Two passes over the input file. First pass notes highest scores, second prints lines. Assumes scores are greater than zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  head -n 1 -
  sort -r -k2,2 -k3,3n
} < file |
awk '
  prev != $2 {
    print
    prev = $2
  }
'
name subject score remarks
sarah  Math    89   good
george History 99   very good
fiona  Geo     65   satis
```